# Can I set unorder_map with lambda function as value type as static

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that is similar to:

```
void function(int a, int& b, int& c){
    std::unorder_map<int,std::function<void()>> branches
       {{1,[&]{do something that takes b and c}},{2,[&]{do another thing that takes b and c}}};
    branches[a]();
    
}
```

the real version code has more branches. The reason that I do this is I don't want to use if statement too much, and I use a macro to generate the code insided lambda function.

But I think it can be improved more. Since variable `a` and the branches will not change, I think the unorder_map could be generated at compile time or at the first call of the function.
So I want to put `static` or `const` in front of it.
But my problem is, since `b` and `c` will change each time the function is called and the lambda function will take b and c, will this code run properly?

Comment: No, if you make `branches` static, it's unlikely to work well. It will be initialized on the first call to the function, and the lambdas will capture references passed to that first call, and ignore parameters passed to subsequent calls. Why don't you pass `b` and `c` as parameters to the lambdas, rather than capturing them?

Comment: If it were me, I'd do `std::function<void(int&, int&)>`. I almost never auto-capture stuff, especially not by reference.

Comment: As a side-note, you should make your map `const`, which prevents `branches[a]` from creating an empty lambda before calling it and crashing if no mapping exists. Better off doing `auto it = branches.find(a); if (it != branches.end()) (*it)();`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you can do that, but it is not nice.

You want to make a dispatcher. And I would always design it as a class.

Parameter handling should be modified to avoid capturing.

But anyway. Here is what you want (one of many potential solutions):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

// Dispatcher
void dispatcherFunction(int a, int& b, int& c) {

    static std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(int&, int&)>> callable{
        {1, [](int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 1 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }},
        {2, [](int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 2 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }},
        {3, [](int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 3 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }},
        {4, [](int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 4 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }},
        {5, [](int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 5 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }}
    };
    if (callable.count(a))   callable[a](b, c);
}
// Test Code
int main() {
    int b{ 11 }, c{ 21 };

    for (int a{ 1 }; a < 6; ++a)
        dispatcherFunction(a, b, c);
}
```

You can also use a compile time `constexpr std::array` to achive what you want.

Basic Example:

```
// Callable functions
void function1(int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 1 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }
void function2(int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 2 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }
void function3(int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 3 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }
void function4(int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 4 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }
void function5(int& b, int& c) { std::cout << 5 << '\t' << b++ << ' ' << c++ << '\n'; }

constexpr std::array<void (*)(int& b, int& c), 5> callable{ {
    function1, function2, function3, function4, function5
} };

// Test Code
int main() {
    int b{ 1 }, c{ 2 };

    for (int a{}; a < 5; ++a)
        callable[a](b, c);
}
```

But as said.

Create a class "Dispatcher" with an interface for registering and unregistering functions and with one `call ()` operator for invoking registered functions.